# Make Protractor sequentially route to different URLs

Tags: javascript, protractor, end-to-end

As expected, `browser.get("http://www.google.com");` routes us to Google.

My question however, concerns routing to different webpages sequentially. I have the use case to route to a set of (hard coded) pre-defined URLs sequentially, and check each web page for a 404.

Let's say I have the following URLs that I want Protractor to route to:

```
http://www.google.com
http://www.amazon.com
http://www.ebay.com
```

And the following end-to-end code:

```
describe("Test links for validity", function() {
    it("should route to Google", function() {
        browser.get("http://www.google.com");
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain("/Error/");
    });

    it("should route to Amazon", function() {
        browser.get("http://www.amazon.com");
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain("/Error/");
    });

    it("should route to Ebay", function() {
        browser.get("http://www.ebay.com");
        expect(browser.driver.getCurrentUrl()).not.toContain("/Error/");
    });
});
```

The problem I face is that Protractor beautifully routes to Google... and then idles. Is there something I miss that makes Protractor actually route to Amazon and Ebay as well?

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is simple!

Instead of using `browser.get("http://www.google.com");` use `browser.driver.get("http://www.google.com");`. This way you are communicating directly to the Web Driver.